# Change origin point of QPainter

Tags: qt, transformation, qpainter

By default `QPainter` has its origin point in top-left corner.
I want to draw shapes but all coordinates that I have are in cartesian system.
So my question - how can I change the origin point to bottom-left corner?
Sure, I can `scale(1,-1)` but then `drawText()` also scaled and prints inverted text. All I nee it just move origin point.

Comment: is it that difficult to add a `height()-y` for each relevant call?

Comment: It's not so diffcult to add that but, as you understand, it is superfluous operation, on the assumption that we can change the origin point. Also I have thousands of shapes and complicated transformation so I want to avoid that.

Comment: A combination of `translate` and `scale` is the solution. However as you already found out, if painter is scaled, text is mirrored/inverted. I also didn't find a good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QPainter painter(this);

painter.translate(this.rect().bottomLeft());
painter.scale(1.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: Again, this will mirror/invert text output which is undesired. And translation should be `rect().center()` to get cartesian coordinates,

Comment: then just don't use scale only translate, and when performing a drawing use negative value for `y`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use void `QPainter::translate ( const QPointF & offset )` method to change origin coordinate. Check docs [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#translate).

Comment: Ok, thanks guys! As I understand it's impossible just to change origin point, without any skaling/transformation. So I will use @Marek R's solution without scaling, as the most usable one.