# pyside: reverse y axis to "math convention"

Tags: qt, pyside, coordinate-systems

It would be a lot more convenient for me, if the layout in the widget would work as it does in math, there's a partial solution to it, but this also turns the text around, so in a sense it doesn't do the trick, because I still have to do all the calculation in the original coordinate system (which is of course manageable, just makes it longer 'cause my intuitive thinking is in the usual Cartesian):

```
def paintEvent(self,event):
        xdim = 500
        ydim = 500
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.scale(1,-1)
        painter.translate(0,ydim)
        painter.drawText(10,10,"1")
        painter.drawText(10,490,"2")
        painter.drawText(490,10,"3")
        painter.drawText(490,490,"4")
```

Is there a way to tell PySide (well, Qt) to be nice and use the math-like cartesian?

Comment: Same question in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014090/change-origin-point-of-qpainter. Apparently there's no other solution than to just translate and use `-y` instead of `y`.

Comment: hmm, then one could technically write a filter which inverts the coordinates and pass everything through ... probably I'm better off just getting used to this system :) Thanks!